# Same paginator for every controller in ZF2

Tags: oop, zend-framework2

I'm writing my first app in ZF2, and I want to create pagination system.

Currently, I have something like this in my controllers:

```
$pagLimit = $this->params()->fromQuery('limit', 1000);
$pagPage = $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1);
$orderDir = $this->params()->fromQuery('dir', 'ASC');
$orderBy = $this->params()->fromQuery('column', 'id');

$result = $this->getMapper()->getList($orderDir, $orderBy);


$paginator = new Paginator(new ArrayAdapter($result));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($pagLimit);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pagPage);
```

I think that my solution is not quite good..

If I want to change e.g. default limit of items per page, I have to modify all my controllers. Also, I have to remember to send two arguments for all mapper methods which are getting lists of data.

My first thought was to use inheritance ("MyController" with methods like: setPaginationParams(), and setPaginator($data)).

Then I would have to remember to invoke "my controller" methods in every controller.

But maybe there is a better way to implement the same paginator for every controller in my module? MVC event? Create custom class and use DI?

What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Could you just give me some hints?

I'm new to ZF2 and OOP concepts. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could always extend the paginator with your own, and have default values set.
You could even just pass in the request object or params object and then let the Paginator internally handle some things for you to save setting up default values etc.